# Variable in mysql query, grouping and ordering

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to get a variable in a MySQL query.

```
$filter = $_GET['fltr'];
require_once('core/dbconnect.php');
if($filter)
{
    $limit = 'LIMIT '. $filter;
}
$lastonline = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logins ORDER BY time DESC GROUP BY username '$limit'");
```

Now the problem is somewhere where I put '$limit' in the query. That doesn't work, but what is the proper way to do this?

It almost works okay now as I get a result only not the absolute correct one.
I changed the code to this:

```
$filter = $_GET['fltr'];
require_once('core/dbconnect.php');
if($filter)
{
$limit = 'LIMIT '. (int) $filter;
}
$lastonline = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logins GROUP BY username ORDER BY time DESC {$limit}");
```

As you can see I had to change GROUP BY and ORDER BY around as that doesnt work.
I did put it in that order for a reason, as now it groups by username first but doesnt take the last login out anymore.

Anyone that knows a solution for this last issue in this query?

Thanks for all of your help in advance!

Comment: You need space between keyoword ``LIMIT`` and ``$filter``

Comment: warning : ___sql injection still exist in world___ i mean your code is vulnerable to sql injection you need to escape all request properly or better use the pdo(prepared statement) ...see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1723893

Comment: what you tried to debug your code and tried to find reason  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things:

1. You need a space between LIMIT and the number;
2. You need to fix your sql injection problem, for example by casting the user-sent variable to `int`;
3. You need to get rid of the quotes in your sql statement around the LIMIT statement;
4. You need to group before your order so you need to switch these two.

So the result would be:

```
if($filter)
{
    $limit = 'LIMIT '. (int) $filter;
}
$lastonline = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logins GROUP BY username ORDER BY time DESC {$limit}");
```

And you should switch to PDO or mysqli and prepared statements as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

**Edit:** To expand on the 4th point, according to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html):

> In general, clauses used must be given in exactly the order shown in
>   the syntax description. For example, a HAVING clause must come after
>   any GROUP BY clause and before any ORDER BY clause.

So `ORDER BY` comes after `GROUP BY`.

Comment: +1 for addressing the issue with example code and suggesting switch to better, more supported SQL interfaces.

Comment: Works (sort of) okay now and thanks for warning me about the MySQL injection. There is only one problem.. I did ORDER BY before GROUP by for a reason. It had to take the last logins out then group by username as now it groups by username but doesnt take the last login anymore.

Comment: @ManouHH You could try something like `SELECT *, MAX(time) FROM ...`.

Answer (score 1):

why its not working because your query is like

```
SELECT * FROM logins ORDER BY time DESC GROUP BY username 'LIMIT4'
```

while it must be like

```
SELECT * FROM logins ORDER BY time DESC GROUP BY username LIMIT 4
```

why you are getting like this ?
you are getting this because of the line below

```
$limit = 'LIMIT'. $filter;
```

so instead try

```
require_once('core/dbconnect.php');
if(isset($_GET['fltr']))
{
  $lastonline = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logins ORDER BY time DESC GROUP BY username LIMIT " . mysql_real_escape_string($limit));
}
```

and more mysql_* function are deprecated use PDO or Mysqli instead and imo use PDO instead

**Good Read**

[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1723893)

**Warning**

Your code is vulnerable to **sql injection** you need to escape/sanitize  all request properly

Answer (score 0):

Add the space as arma suggested, and consider setting `$limit = '';` before the `if ($filter)` block (not strictly necessary, but good practice).

If this is just pseudocode, you can ignore the rest of this, but you really should consider sterilizing the $filter variable before blindly inserting it into a DB query, since `mysql_query` doesn't handle escaping and such. In this specific instance, `$filter = (int)$_GET['fltr']; should work just fine. Consider checking out the [PHP MySQL PDO Object](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) as well.

Answer (score 0):

First escape $filter , then put a space between limit and $filter . Like "LIMIT ".$filter